# Remove google map marker while animation is playing

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I have a google map marker animation by using the postDelayed with setLocation as in the following pseudo code:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

   void Run(){
     // set marker location to new x,y
     //  if there is still more time left
     // handler.postdDelayed(this, 300)

}}, 5000);
```

My question is, lets say I want to terminated the animation halfway by removing the marker. If I just do marker.remove() while animation is running then I will get a problem because it attempts to setlocation on removed marker. So how would you do it?
Thanks

Comment: if marker is a global ivar, test to see if null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting the marker invisible and then deleting it (when the animation finished)?

Comment: That's actually great suggestion!  Thanks a lot. I will accept it unless a "best practice" answer comes around